# request file not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to request file from fileupload that is created in html. my question is quite simple how do i do this? 
i know there is this option : `HttpPostedFile File = Request.Files["imagem"];` but when i try to do that my `File` returns `NULL`.
I dont know what am i doing wrong, but even this simple code example is not working and i dont know why .

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpPostedFile File = Request.Files["imagem"];
      if ( File != null)
     Response.Write("Sucesso");
    }
   </form>
</body>
```

and here is my aspx code example :

```
  <input type="file" name="image"  class="image-upload" /></div>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

can any one explain what am i doing wrong ? thank you

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, you wish to retrieve a file being uploaded by a user on the server?

Comment: yes as simple as that, but i dont want to use aspx file upload.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323246/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-web-server-in-asp.net-by-using-visual-c-.net

Comment: You should include the form tag in your aspx code as there are attributes you need to have that may be causing issues.

Comment: Might just be a typo on Stack Overflow but your name in the `Button1_Click` is `imagem` and your name on the aspx is `image`

Comment: i have already seen the example you have given, but the problem is that i am creating fileuploads dunamically, and therefore i cannot give atribute runat="server" to tham simply because it will not be reconized

Comment: Try including an `id="image"` on your input as well, but again add your form tag to your question.

Comment: Okay so as I expected it is your form tag that is causing issues. Include these attributes and let me know if you still have a problem. `method="post"` `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: thank you, but now can you explain to me why sometimes it works without 
  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  because when i first find the code that i have shown on my question my application worked fine.

Comment: The `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is for files so if you have regular inputs the form will work just fine without it.  And the `method="post"` is not required but is good practice to be explicit in what it is the form is going to be doing.

Comment: You say *"I cannot give atribute runat="server" to tham simply because it will not be reconized"*.  But, when you create asp.net controls dynamically, you do not need to give that attribute at all.  If you are working in asp.net, you really should get comfortable with using asp.net controls, including creating them dynamically.  If you are using a platform, your life gets a lot easier if you use it as its designers intended.

Answer (score 1):

Might just be a typo on here, but change your `imagem` to `image`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpPostedFile File = Request.Files["image"];

    if ( File != null)
        Response.Write("Sucesso");
}
```

In your aspx page you need to tell the form that it will be using files.  I don't think its required but its good practice to also include an id in your input that matches your name.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image"  class="image-upload" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend going with the asp.net file upload control:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="pictureUpload" class="form-control input-sm input-spacing" runat="server" />
```

You **can** create these dynamically

```
FileUpload OneUpload = new FileUpload();
OneUpload.ID = "Upload" + MyIdNumber;
UploadsDiv.Controls.Add(OneUpload);
```

Then to access the file, you have:

```
pictureUpload.SaveAs(FilePathAndName);
```

You can also access different properties of the posted file...

```
pictureUpload.PostedFile.FileName
pictureUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength
pictureUpload.PostedFile.ContentType
```

Comment: @DavidLee - his reason for saying that FileUploads are not an option is that he cannot add the runat="server" attribute.  But, you do not have to add that attribute when you create an ASP control dynamically.

Comment: Not sure what the persons use case is, but that makes sense to me.

Comment: @DavidLee - I am not sure what you are saying that makes sense to you.  Is it what he said, and exactly what part of it, or my response to his comment about not being able to add the runat="server".

Comment: What you are saying makes sense to me, i am just not sure the reason as to why OP cannot use `runat="server"` and if its more than just the attribute itself.